# An actual Heter Iska Agreement

Tags: lending-interest-ribbis

Can anyone provide a copy of an actual heter iska agreement used for example by a bank in Israel for purposes of business loans or mortgages?  I don't mean a haskama that such and such bank operates according to heter iska, but an actual heter iska agreement between two individuals or between a bank and a customer.

Comment: like Roman Numeral II? http://www.jlaw.com/Forms/

Comment: @Danno I do believe that's what I'm looking for, but I'll have to actually look at it before I know.

Comment: @Danno I looked at the monthly one and that's what I'm looking for in principle, do you think that's what used by banks here in Israel?  I don't think any bank here would sign an agreement like that...

Comment: I know precious little about banking in any country. That's why I didn't give this as an answer.

Comment: http://www.zomet.org.il/?CategoryID=264&ArticleID=258 is pretty relevant and a good reference for other sources about usury in the modern economies.

Comment: @DoubleAA Thanks, looks like a great source.

Answer (score 4):

there's one [here](http://www.din.org.il/files/2013/05/%D7%A9%D7%98%D7%A8-%D7%94%D7%99%D7%AA%D7%A8-%D7%A2%D7%A1%D7%A7%D7%94-%D7%9B%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%AA%D7%94-%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%AA-%D7%A4%D7%A0%D7%97%D7%A1.pdf)
The first page is the document, and the 2nd page are the halachos pertaining to hetter iska.

@Tzvi **HERE IS THE ENGLISH VERSION OF THE SAME DOCUMENT:**

You may need to [Sign in](https://www.evernote.com/Login.action) to your account to access this [page](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s502/res/a82e6223-40c4-4438-b11b-e15c5a8af9c9/%D7%A9%D7%98%D7%A8%20%D7%94%D7%99%D7%AA%D7%A8%20%D7%A2%D7%A1%D7%A7%D7%90%20%D7%91%D7%90%D7%A0%D7%92%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%AA%20%282%29%20%281%29.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

While doing research for [my question here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/48329/5323), I found [Beis Din of America](http://bethdin.org/)'s [Iska agreement](http://bethdin.org/docs/PDF15-Shtar_Iska.pdf).

Here it is:

> ## SHTAR ISKO
>
> ### Agreement Concerning Interest on Loans
>
> #### Introduction
>
> Jewish Religious Law strictly prohibits the paying or receiving of interest on loans made between Jews. However, when monies
>   are advanced in the course of a business transaction, an agreement may
>   be entered into, whereby the provider and receiver of these funds are
>   considered equal partners. This partnership is based upon the
>   stipulation that, upon request, every loss must be attested to by two
>   trustworthy witnesses, and all profits verified by oath. All
>   consequent profits and losses are then equally shared. However, in
>   order to avoid these very stringent requirements, the provider of the
>   funds, under this “Shtar Isko”, agrees to waive his share of the
>   profits in lieu of receiving a fixed percentage of the money advanced.
>   This percentage is then considered profit, rather than interest on a
>   loan. This agreement becomes effective when the receiver of the funds
>   executes a form as set below.
>
> #### The Agreement
>
> I, the undersigned, have received from ____________________________________, the sum of ____________  repayable over ______ years for the purpose of transacting business in
>   connection with 
>   ____________________________________ in which profits and losses are to be equally shared. However, the  said
>   ____________________________________ has agreed that in lieu of such sharing of profits and losses,  which would require substantiation of
>   all losses by two trustworthy witnesses, and verification of  all
>   profits by oath, he shall accept my payment of an annual percentage of
>   ______% of the said sum of 
>   ____________ and waive all other profits which may be earned from the advanced funds. I have  received a token payment of $1.00 from the
>   said ____________________________________ for my efforts in 
>   connection with this undertaking, and have signed herewith the receipt
>   of the said $____________.
>
> SIGNED THIS ______ day of
>   __________________ at _______________________________.
>
> __________________________________________
>   Recipient’s Signature

Comment: many say that the language of  "in lieu of " in the document invalidates the heter iska.